# Oracle sql query to to obtain records for a date range in IST

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to write sql query to obtain records for a date range in IST format.
We are storing data in the database in GMT format.

```
select * 
from tableA a 
where to_date(a.end_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') between date1 and date2;
```

(end_date is one of the column in tableA table)

Now date1 and date2 should fetch the records from database in IST time zone.

How i can write sql query for the above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try the following query

```
SELECT FROM_TZ (
               CAST (SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP)--replace sysdate with your date column
                , 'GMT'
               )
        AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta'
  FROM DUAL;
```

In My case timezone is CET , and there is 3.5 hour difference from INDIA

```
select systimestamp from dual

7/30/2013 4:24:10.379910 PM +02:001


SELECT FROM_TZ (
               CAST (SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP)--replace sysdate with your date column
                , 'GMT'
               )
        AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta'
  FROM DUAL;

7/30/2013 7:54:10.000000 PM +05:30
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply gaurav. Actually We are storing data in the database in GMT format. But my java application is in EST format. Now i need a pull a report which gives in the IST format.For this in where clause how i can apply the condition.